# How to verify the text present in the modal dialog using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I have a webpage which has a 'see Terms' option. On clicking 'see Terms' a modal dialog box opens. I want to verify the text in the modal dialog. The problem I am facing is that how to switch to modal dialog box from the main window. I tried the driver.getWindowHandles() but that dowsn't work. Please suggest how can I switch focus to dialog box and get it's text.

I am using Selenium 2.52.0 and java as a language.

[image]

Comment: You need to switch only when there is seperate window, But I think modal dialog boxhtml code is in same window. Also checked if there is frame then switch frame first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI simply use like below it will work **NOTE** please update your selenium version.

```
String contentOfTerms = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='terms_content']/p")).getText();
System.out.println(contentOfTerms);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It says cannot locate the element.

Comment: hi plz use this xpath //*[@class='terms_content_team_upgrade_cs5_promo']/div[2]/p plz confirm if it helps

Comment: that works. Thanks :)
But can you tell me hoe did you compute this xpath?
I am using a firefox plugin firepath to get the xpath and that gives me a different xpath : html/body/div[10]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/p[1] which doesn't work for this.

Comment: yeah i have used custom xpath generated by me not by any tool and to generate your custom xpath u have to understand how to do that and telling that thing over here is not possible but you can search for the same definitely you will get some crucial information regarding that thanks

Comment: I googled it and found the required information. 
Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a separate window, so you shouldn't do anything with getWindowHandles(). Just try to assert by getting the text with browser.findElement(modal path).getText() on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch window if it is in different frame but its does not look like a different frame although if it is in different frame the try and use following code which will switch parent to child window:

```
public void windowSwitch()
            {
                String parentWin = driver.getWindowHandle();    
            parentWin1=parentWin;
                Set<String> allwin =driver.getWindowHandles();
            for(String child : allwin)
            {
            if(!child.equals(parentWin))
                {
                driver.switchTo().window(child);
                    }
              }
            }
```

And if it is a dialog box only then use following code to get string from it:

```
        public String alert()
        {    String str;
            Alert alert =  driver.switchTo().alert();  
            str= alert.getText();
            alert.accept();
            return  str;

        }
```

Comment: It is a modal dialog box. No new window is created. 
It is not an Alert as well. If I treat it as Alert then I get a NoAlertPresentException.

Answer (score 0):

driver.switchTo().activeElement(); ///to switch into active popupelement...

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='terms_content']/p")).getText();//to get a text of a element you given itll work for you..